# Where are the files located when creating them with IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() in Monogame with Android?

Tags: c#, android, xna, monogame, isolatedstoragefile

I've tried to create files with Monogame for Android but the problem is that I don't know where they are located.

I used this code:

```
    var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    store.CreateFile("test.txt");
```

**So, where is the test.txt file?**

And to be 100% sure that the file actually exists I ran this code:

```
    if (store.FileExists("test.txt"))
    {

    }
```

and that code is true so now I know that the file exist even if I can't find it.

I tried to search for the file everywhere in my project and I also searched for it in my phone but no luck there.

I want to be able to move files from my computer to the gameproject and read/write to those files via my Phone.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into [`TitleContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.titlecontainer.aspx). That's the more cross platform approach to access the isolated storage I believe. As to where the actual files are, sorry I can't help you there.